# How to use a PDF in a presentation

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, preview, keynote

I have to make a little keynote tomorrow, and I have all the slides saved as PDFs. I will be using a projector as a second screen to my laptop.
What's the best way to transform this long PDF document into something more slidy?
If I open in with built-in Preview, I get some annoying issues such as the page number that pops out on the bottom of the slide whenever I flip a page and the non-full-screen-adapting when the ratio of the PDF isn't the same as the ratio of the screen.

So, any solutions?

*Note* I don't own a Keynote copy, so options like [PDF to Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html) are not valid ones.

Comment: I suspect you can't alter PDF rations - they are designed to be as the originator sets and the viewer cannot alter - which is why I prefer vector graphics or HTML, or I suspect Keynote slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched to [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) from Preview for presenting PDFs on a data projector. It has more & better presentation options and it’s free. Starting with Lion, Preview.app drove me crazy. Regarding screen ratio: If I see correctly, both Applications will **not** change the aspect ratio of the PDF when in presentation mode (e.g. for square PDFs)

Comment: Thank you, I gave it a try and it worked much better than Preview did. It was driving me crazy too! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question a few seconds after I first asked it.
The first issue (page number popping out when flipping pages) is easily gone if, instead of using simple Full Screen mode, you use Slideshow (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) mode.

Still having problems with screen ratio though.